# Error: no matching function for call to 'ros::Nodehandle::advertise()'

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Error

```
/home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/videoFeedListener.cpp: In constructor ‘ImageConverter::ImageConverter()’:
/home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/videoFeedListener.cpp:67:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const char [9], int)’
     circle_pub_ = nh_.advertise("/circles", 1);
```

### Code

```
class ImageConverter {
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
  ros::Publisher circle_pub_;
  
  public:
  ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_)
  {

    // Subscribe to the Bottom Raw Image
    image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/ardrone/bottom/image_raw", 1,  
                &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);

    // Advertisng the Circles being detected from this 
    circle_pub_ = nh_.advertise("/circles", 1); 

    cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW1);
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255307/error:-no-matching-function-for-call-to-%27ros::nodehandle::advertise()%27/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the message type that you are publishing on topic /circles?

```
ros::Publisher pub = handle.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("my_topic", 1);
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   You are missing this part
```

---

Originally posted by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) with karma: 271 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
Yes, this works!